# How to assign 'selected' attr in 'select/option' tags based of option value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select input that contains multiple options (each with diff values). I would like to assign the attr 'selected' to whichever option that correspond to an X value.
This is my code:

```
// For example if x=3, then I need the option with value=3 to be 'selected'. 
// How do I achieve that?

<select class="className" name="profile" id="profile">
                <option value="1">Lion</option>
                <option value="2">Tiger</option>
                <option value="3">Panther</option>
                <option value="4">Leopard</option>
                <option value="5">Jaguar</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: @AlwaysHelping sorry just read the post and about to try it out now.

Comment: NO worries. Please try my answer below and let me know.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping how do I compare the option values if my data comes from the user DB? 
opt.value ==  user.profile

Comment: You need to extract the values first and then assign to this function as `x` value accordingly. Or if its only a `single select option` then just `var x = db value` - It should work.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping sorry i am very new at this. So I am using EJS. I have 'user' rendered from the backend containing that user's data. I need the options value be selected to whatever 'user.profilepic' value is. I tried directly doing user.profilepic as x but I really don't think thats how we do it? I don't think the script tag recognizes data from the backend?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping so do we create a function with a parameter, then pass the DBvalue as the argument during that function call?

Comment: On the frontend you need to get user data in ejs template and from their you will set the `var x = dbvalue` it will be hard to tell exactly. What you are after. Ideally post another question with EJS templates and some other requirement of this someone will be able to help exactly whats needed

Comment: Yes there will be something that.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method and `for` loop and [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) to make sure it always option is loaded on `DOM` ready.

**Demo:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var x = '3' //x=3
  var select = document.querySelector('#profilepicChoice');
  var option = select.options;
  for (var opt, j = 0; opt = option[j]; j++) {
    if (opt.value == x) {
      select.selectedIndex = j;
      break;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="profilepic" id="profilepicChoice">
  <option value="1">Lion</option>
  <option value="2">Tiger</option>
  <option value="3">Panther</option>
  <option value="4">Leopard</option>
  <option value="5">Jaguar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply change the element value with javascript:

```
<script>
    // sample x value
    var x = 3;

    (function() {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById('profile');
        dropdown.value = x;
    })();
</script>
```